# Calling Oracle stored procedure from local with native query working fine but when deploy to QA , stored procedure is not found

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, oracle12c

I am calling a stored procedure in a local environment like

```
this.em.createNativeQuery("BEGIN DBO.storedProcedurePersonal(); END;").executeUpdate();
```

And it's working fine totally, Now I have to deploy war file on the QA app server and trying to call endpoint which ultimately calls, it's throw "identifier must be declared" which is like the stored procedure is not found in the QA DB environment, However, I can able to execute the same command in QA DB server without any issue. I have raised the issue to the APP server (UNIX) team as well as QA DB (DBA) team, but the issue is just like back end forth between them.

Please help somebody.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
DBO.storedProcedurePersonal()
```

means that

- procedure's name is `storedProcedurePersonal`
- and is owned by user whose name is `DBO`

If you're now using a different connection (which might be the case as you mentioned different **application** servers - did the database (or username) change as well?), maybe you'll have to change `DBO` to something else.

---

Also, mind letter case. In Oracle, object names are by default all in uppercase, but you can reference them any way you want. It means that - by default - `storedProcedurePersonal` = `storedprocedurepersonal` = `STOREDPROCEDUREperSonAL` = ..., but - if you used double quotes to create a  procedure, then you have to reference it using double quotes and exactly match letter case every time.